# Detecting and Tracking objects with background subtraction

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a video processing project which involves tracking of human subjects. I have a stable background scene and whenever the subject comes in to the frame there are minor lighting effects changes. I tried using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 but it doesnt seem to work well then I tried using this piece of code :

```
cv::Mat temp;
cv::subtract(camFrame,backg,temp);
cv::threshold(temp,temp,25,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

camFrame is the grayscale version of frame from camera. backg is the background frame which is already captured and stored. But this code doesnt seem to extract the foreground subjects well and lighting effects are also shown as foreground...I will be glad if somebody can provide me some suggestion along with some bits of code..

Comment: before you start to reinvent the wheel, please have a look at the HOG detector samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp

Comment: I need to track humans from all angles partly or fully...Thats I moved to background subtraction...